# Node.js crypto data greater than mod len

Tags: node.js, saml, cryptojs

I am trying to decrypt the SAML Response assertion.

I have the following SAML response

```
<samlp:Response ID="_c5857dc7-2109-4fd3-beb0-e07756bba622" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2023-12-18T09:59:24.040Z" Destination="https://sp.com/api/auth/saml" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="_1702893559452"
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<Issuer
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://adsf.sp.io/adfs/services/trust
</Issuer>
<samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
</samlp:Status>
<EncryptedAssertion
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
        xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
        <KeyInfo
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <e:EncryptedKey
                xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                </e:EncryptionMethod>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <ds:X509Data
                        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                            <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=idp-domain.com, O=idp-o, S=idp-S, C=sa</ds:X509IssuerName>
                            <ds:X509SerialNumber>0</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                        </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
                <e:CipherData>
                    <e:CipherValue>*Encrypted Data*</e:CipherValue>
                </e:CipherData>
            </e:EncryptedKey>
        </KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>*Large Encrypted Data*</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</EncryptedAssertion>
```

</samlp:Response>

I took the encrypted data in the `CipherValue` node and tried decrypting it using the following code.

```
import crypto from 'crypto'
const buffer = Buffer.from(
            '*Large Encrypted Data*',
            'base64'
        )
             crypto.privateDecrypt(
                    {
                        key: privateKey,
                        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_NO_PADDING
                    },
                    buffer
                )
```

instead of getting the decrypted data, I am getting the following error

`error:0406506C:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:data greater than mod len`

Should split my encrypted data? or is my decryption method wrong?

Comment: `rsa-oaep-mgf1p` specifies an OAEP padding, you're specifying no padding...

Comment: Changed it but same error

Comment: Changed it to what?

Comment: For RSA, the ciphertext cannot be larger than the key size. The whole scenario looks more like hybrid encryption (aes256-cbc for the actual data and RSA/OAEP for the AES key).

Comment: @AKX change padding to RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING

Comment: @Topaco Can you explain more, I am new to encryption/decryption.

Comment: @Topaco Will try it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256310/discussion-between-sohayb-saleh-and-topaco).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for an answer.
The decryption is a normal XML decryption, you can use this library it works like a charm.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-encryption

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.